# Drawing on transparent form with a transparent color leaves the back color showing

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, transparent

I'm creating a transparent form (done by using a transparency key and setting the background) which I am then attempting to draw on using a Bitmap buffer. All my drawing is done using the buffers graphics instance and then drawn directly to the form using the forms graphics reference in the OnPaint.

My issue is that every time I draw something with an alpha value the back color shows through. Is there a way to get around this so the alpha works as intended (not showing the transparency key back color)?

Comment: You need per-pixel alpha blending instead of a colorkey.  Not directly supported by Winforms, you need to do [some hacking](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20758/Alpha-Blended-Windows-Forms).

Comment: @HansPassant Can you expand upon this? I don't know to much about the WinAPI.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok so what you suggested worked but it draws itself directly to the desktop which is something I can't have (it'll draw even when the window is hidden).

Comment: I think it uses a 2nd form to draw onto, not the desktop.

Comment: @TaW not from what I'm experiencing. If I put another window in front of the one being drawn on the drawing appears above the newly focused window.